# How to create a multi-select with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a multiple-`v-select` for users, so they can select multiple options. A computed property filters this selection. I cannot get this to work with multiple options.

Removing the `multiple` setting from `v-select` works, but that means that users can only select one option, while they should be able to select more than one.

```html
<template>
  <v-select
    v-model="selectofficeperks"
    :items="officeperks"
    multiple />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      officeperks: ['Tafeltennis','Tafelvoetbal', 'Pooltafel']
      selectofficeperks:[],
      jobs:[],
      jobofficeperks:'',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filtered() {
      return this.jobs.filter(result => {
        let officeperks = this.selectofficeperks;

        if (officeperks != '') {
          return (officeperks.includes(result.jobofficeperks))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When selecting multiple options it does not give a result from the computed filter. The jobs array gets filled by data from Firestore, the values are exactly the same.

If I remove the `multiple` setting, it does return a value, but I'm guessing that's because it only tries to find one value, which is not what I want. Users have to be able to select multiple values.

Comment: `officeperks` is Array - you should check `officeperks.length > 0` rather than `officeperks != ''` Also, items in `officeperks` are Strings - so when you do `officeperks.includes()` - the argument for `includes()` must also be a String (and not array of strings)

Comment: What do you want to achieve here, like what do you want to happen in the filter? I don't quite understand